# Adding react-d3 to my react-native app causes a error

Tags: d3.js, react-native, react-d3

I am quite new to `reactJS`, and have just started working with `react-native`.

I added `react-d3` using npm install --save-dev react-d3 but when I refresh or rebuild the app I am getting:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object
(evaluating 
'require('BatchedBridge').flushedQueue')

{
 "line":1 ,
 "column": 25
}
```

If I remove or uninstall `react-d3` from the library it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: You can't just magically use web-React modules in your React Native project. There are loads of things from the browser that aren't available in React Native.

Comment: Like I said am new to this so and can't seem to find documentation on use. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

D3JS requires browser DOM, which React Native doesn't directly have.

The only way to possibly do this is to use a WebView to wrap the D3JS view.

It could get pretty messy, but it is doable.

Comment: Thank you. After spending the last few days with it seems to be the only way so far.