# Render graphs in react-native

Tags: android, ios, d3.js, graph, react-native

I'm trying to render a couple of different graphs in my react-native project, with a goal of supporting both iOS and Android. Preferably, I'd like to simply use a framework like https://github.com/esbullington/react-d3, but I'm not sure it can be done since there is no real DOM in react-native. Could one somehow get around this problem and get D3 to work in native, or could a similar result be achieved some other way? I would prefer not having to write native code if at all possible.

Comment: Looks like you can use the WebView with the react-d3 library. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29415615/1349269

Comment: Yeah, though so as well, but seems that WebView is only supported on iOS as of now: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: True, but depending on your timeline, they may add it soon enough to be useful. In the mean time, you can bridge the gap with this... https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-webview-android

Comment: Quite a small timeline I'm afraid, but that link you gave me might be a solution in the short term. Thanks, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Let me know how it goes. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout 
https://github.com/hswolff/BetterWeather

which was made using [d3js](https://d3js.org/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that particular library is built specifically for the browser. You should find a library / framework like D3 but built specifically for react native. Here are a few examples:

https://github.com/tomauty/react-native-chart

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm afraid the react-native-chart seems to be unmanaged, and not updated for android. The other library works only for android. If possible, I'd like a solution where I could keep one single code base.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that one wasn't being maintained! Here is another, but not very robust: https://github.com/PrazAs/react-native-charts .